# jQuery start animation fadeOut from begining

Tags: jquery

I need to fadeOut element (information box). But when I am in middle of animation and click fadeOut again, I want to start fadeOut from begining.

Checkbox.change: start fadeout----->user again click checkbox.change (return to begin animation)

my code:

```
if($('#inform-box').is(':animated')) {
  //alert('YES, IT IS ANIMATED');
  $('#inform-box').hide();
  //$(this).stop().animate({opacity:'100'});
}else{
 //alert('NOT ANIMATED');
}
$('#inform-box').show().fadeOut( 4000 );
$('#inform-box').html('fadeOut text');
```

Comment: opacity 100 is the same as opacity 1 to the eye.. you wanna increase in tiny increments with opacity.. like 0.05 > 0.8 depending on colors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `stop()` to stop the current animation, then reset the element's `opacity` to `1`:

```
$('#inform-box').stop().css({opacity: 1}).fadeOut(4000);
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hEtRD/).